# Android thread and handler are not stoping

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep

I tried simple code in android, that changes a textView every second, to the number of seconds that passed:

onCreate method:

```
        Runnable runnable = new Wait(15);

        sleep = new Thread(runnable);

        sleep.start();
```

a new class that extends Thread:

```
    class Wait extends Thread {
        int seconds;

        Wait(int seconds) {
            this.seconds = seconds;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1 ; i < this.seconds + 1; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                int finalI = i;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(finalI + "");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'm trying(without any success) to stop it:

```
        // onClick button method
        sleep.interrupt();
```

Why it's not working?
It does not stop the thread. It just cut the sleep time. After that, the text keeps the change (the loop keeps running).

Comment: Did you solve a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Calling to

```
sleep.interrupt();
```

not stop a thread it [just set thread's interrupt status and if this thread is blocked for example by `Thread.sleep()` then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an `InterruptedException`.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#interrupt()) (follow the linnk to see more delales).

That's why you should check every time `Thread.isInterrupted()` and complete `run()` method executing(by calling `return` for example) from `catch` block when get a `InterruptedException` or create your own flag which will illuminate thread interrupting.

You can change your code like this:

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1 ; i < (this.seconds + 1) && !isInterrupted(); i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }

                int finalI = i;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(finalI + "");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Or with your own flag:

```
class Wait extends Thread {
    int seconds;

    private volatile boolean iInterruptThisThread = false;

    Wait(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }
    
    public void interruptThreadMySelf() {
        iInterruptThisThread = true;
        super.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < (this.seconds + 1) && !iInterruptThisThread; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if(iInterruptThisThread) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            int finalI = i;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(finalI + "");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
class Wait extends Thread {
    int seconds;

    private volatile boolean iInterruptThisThread = false;

    Wait(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }
    
    public void interruptThreadMySelf() {
        iInterruptThisThread = true;
        super.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < (this.seconds + 1) && !iInterruptThisThread; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if(iInterruptThisThread) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            int finalI = i;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setText(finalI + "");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And call the `sleep.interruptThreadMySelf()`

By the way you can use `sleep = new Wait(15);` instead of `sleep = new Thread(runnable);`.